# How can I code the same scrolling effect as the Facebook home page right bar (with the trending and sponsored ads)?

Tags: jquery, html, facebook, css

At the top of the Facebook page, I see the trending topics and the ads. As I scroll further down the page, I only see the advertisements. How can I mimic this effect?

Comment: Not really a question for here. But it's all front end code so you can simply go through their code and find out.

Comment: Trending wouldn't be front end, though.

Comment: @Feign how it functions, that is, its stickiness is.

Answer (score 0):

You can google `sticky sidebar`. There are many jQuery and css plugin for doing this.

You need to work with, scroll event of your browser using JavaScript or jQuery and use position property of your element css change it with JavaScript (jQuery).

You can find a good example, demo and tutorial in:

[Tutorial: jQuery “Sticky Sidebar”](http://andrewhenderson.me/wp-content/tutorials/jquery-sticky-content/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of events in a database and keep moving the highest to the top.